# How to make even intensity straight lines in GIMP with a stylus

Tags: gimp, wacom

When I want to make a straight line in gimp, I press shift and press at one point then another and it makes a straight line in GIMP between those two points.

However, when I do this with a Wacom drawing tablet, I get totally different results. I get like a gradient of intensity between the first point and the second. See for yourself:

[image]

As you can see, the intensity of the stroke goes from zero at point A and to the desired intensity at point B (as hard as I pressed the wacom-pen at point B)

Can you please tell me, how do I make the intenisty of the line uniform to the intensity at point B? That is, if I press harder at point B, the entire line should be more intense or if I press lightly at point B the entire line should be light.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the Tool options, I see you have the Dynamics set to "Basic Dynamics". Set it to "Dynamics off" instead.

Comment: Yea, but then I'll have zero control over the intensity. It'll be 100% intense and it won't look good when all the other strokes are like 30% intense.

Comment: i want the intensity to be dynamic (a function of how hard I press) but constant from point A to point B

Comment: @JeniaIvanov You can change the opacity of the brush in the tool options.  Dynamic means "changeable". You can't have it both dynamic and constant.  That doesn't really make much sense.